# how to open kdb+ port on specific path?

Tags: kdb

When I set `\p 8080` I can have calls to `http://localhost:8080/` to interact with kdb+.

How can I do it for this url:
`http://localhost:8080/somepath`
?

The use case if for my app that send HTTP requests to the kdb process to get data from the DB. For react reasons that are out of scope here (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520984/how-to-tell-react-to-use-the-proxy-server)) I can't use `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: Can you explain to us your use case here? Are you trying to access some data from a kdb process listening on port 8080?

Comment: @CathalO'Neill added

Answer (score 1):

By default the root server for the q webserver is located in a folder called `html` under your `QHOME` folder.
If you had a html document called `mydoc.html` then you could place it at, for instance,

```
$QHOME/html/example/mydoc.html
```

and reach it by calling

```
http://localhost:8080/example/mydoc.html
```

There is some info here: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/custom-web/

Comment: I don't have a `html` folder in my `QHOME` folder (I am running V3.6 x32 because I want it to work offline).

Comment: You will need to create the folder yourself. 
Alternatively you can edit the .h.HOME variable in your q session to point to a different folder of your choice