# how to tell react to use the proxy server

Tags: reactjs, kdb

I have a react app served on `http://localhost:3000`.
I also have a kdb+ server on `http://localhost:8080`.
I send HTTP request to the kdb+ to get data from the DB and because of CORS I added a proxy in the react app package.json file.

The problem is, that because I call the kdb+ server from `http://localhost:8080/?getData` (without relative paths) and because when I call the kdb+ server inside the app I use `fetch('/?getData')` (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902840/enabling-cors-in-create-react-app-utility) answer) react "knows" this url so it doesn't use the proxy.

How can I solve this?

Is there a way to set react to work only on `http://localhost:3000/somepath`? I tried setting the `homepage` parameter in the package.json file and the app worked both on `/` and `/somepath`.

Maybe the solution is to set kdb+ to listen on `http://localhost:8080/sompath`? I searched for it and couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy in package.json not affecting fetch request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365577/proxy-in-package-json-not-affecting-fetch-request)

Comment: @HaraldGliebe No because I don't know how to enable CORS in the kdb server. and the second approach doesn't seem related, and if it does, I didn't understand how.